# Integrating Apache with PKCS#11 device via engine_pkcs11 and OpenSSL

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl, mod-ssl, cryptography, debian-jessie

I have problem with mod_ssl exactly with SSLCryptoDevice directive. When I run command "openssl engine" returns all available engines including pkcs11 (libengine-pkcs11-openssl), but When I set SSLCryptoDevice pkcs11 in mod_ssl configuration and I try to start Apache, returns error  "SSLCryptoDevice: Invalid argument; must be one of:" but now engine pkcs11 isn't listed. In openssl works well.

Some system info: Debian 8 x64, OpenSSL 1.0.1k, Apache 2.4.10

Apache start error: http://pastebin.com/b4GLaSHL

OpenSSL engines: http://pastebin.com/kXNYG2Yw

Comment: This does now work straightforwardly with sufficiently recent versions, see: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/configuring-applications-to-use-cryptographic-hardware-through-pkcs-11_security-hardening#using-hsms-protecting-private-keys-in-apache-and-nginx_configuring-applications-to-use-cryptographic-hardware-through-pkcs-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PKCS#11` support isn't native in `mod_ssl`. See:

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42687

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42688

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52473

You can try apply this patchs, but these is **not** suitable for production use.

Another alternative is you use [mod_nss](https://fedorahosted.org/mod_nss/).
`mod_nss` uses NSS as the crypto library instead of OpenSSL and supports
`PKCS#11`.

Answer (score 0):

PKCS11 is support in mod_ssl from v2.4.42 onwards.

> As an alternative to storing certificates and private keys in files, a
> certificate identifier can be used to identify a certificate stored in
> a token. Currently, only PKCS#11 URIs are recognized as certificate
> identifiers, and can be used in conjunction with the OpenSSL pkcs11
> engine. If SSLCertificateKeyFile is omitted, the certificate and
> private key can be loaded through the single identifier specified with
> SSLCertificateFile.

An example from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile

```
# Example use of a certificate and private key from a PKCS#11 token:
SSLCertificateFile "pkcs11:token=My%20Token%20Name;id=45"
```